# JDE for Emacs for JDK 6.10

Tags: java, emacs

Is there a version of JDE for emacs that supports the JDK 6.10?  I haven't been able to find any information on this.  While it runs, every time I attempt to compile files the JDE says that it doesn't recognize my JDK version and reverts to assuming it is a Java5 version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made following customizations for JDE:

```
'(jde-bug-debugger-host-address "127.0.0.1")
'(jde-bug-jre-home "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun")
'(jde-compile-option-debug (quote ("all" (t nil nil))))
'(jde-debugger (quote ("jdb")))
'(jde-global-classpath (quote ("." "/usr/share/java/" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/")))
'(jde-jdk-doc-url "/usr/share/doc/sun-java6-jdk/html/api/index.html")
'(jde-jdk-registry (quote (("1.5" . "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun"))))
'(jde-regexp-jar-file "/usr/share/java/regexp.jar")
'(jde-sourcepath (quote (".")))
```

So it compiles without complaints, although I have jdk 1.6.0.07.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your paths up in the configuration settings by "registering" a JDK version using `M-x customize-variable` and choosing `jde-jdk-registry`.  Save that state, then do `M-x customize-variable` again, customize `jde-jdk` and pick the one you want.

That *should* do it; if not, give us a little more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've done that.  The problem is when I call 'jde-compile, The message 'The JDE does not recognize JDK6.0.10 JDK. Assume JDK 1.5 Javac?" appears.  Also, It doesn't look like the Java6 constructs, such as annotations, have been defined in the syntax checking or indentation rules.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like a bug.  There is a mailing list off the JDEE site for such things.